# Center aligning of the text in dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I have searched answer for this question .. But i found one solution in SO .. One user had suggested to use padding-left or this qustion.

```
<select>
   <option>one</option>
   <option>one-two</option>
</select>
```

When i add padding-left it works fine with the browser .. When i check my dropdown in devices , its not aligned at the center as i expected .. I have given values for padding-left in percentage and pixels also .. Is there any other way to do it so that it works fine in all browsers and devices??

Comment: have you tried `select { text-align: center }` ?

Comment: `select, option { text-align: center; }` is not working?

Comment: `"so that it works fine in all browsers and devices"` Probably not with just CSS. Select elements are horrible to design for cross-browser. The _most reliable_ way would be to create your own custom element that acts as select box - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508154/the-correct-way-of-styling-a-select-menu-for-cross-browser-functionality

Comment: It's working in ff but not in chrome ..

Comment: @MLeFevre , Yeah that's a better solution with more works..

Comment: `text-align: center;` doesnt work in opera either.